# How to have a full width background image without resizing or cropping

Tags: html, css

I want to have a full width background, but when I use background-size: cover, part of it gets cut off. With background-size: contain, it repeats on the right side. 
Is it possible to have the full size without cropping or resizing or repeating?

CSS:

```
.home-3 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/a/r9JRp");
    background-size: contain;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: http://tinypng.com there's > 30Mb of images to download

Comment: I know. I still have to resize them. I just wanted to make this work first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the following CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
.home-3{
background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Edited and tested.

Comment: Almost there! It still gets cut off, though. That's normal?

Comment: I managed to hack it a bit by adding some bottom padding: http://output.jsbin.com/waliqa

Comment: Is it also possible to do it without the scrolling? To fit the screen?

Comment: Using 100vw and 100vh removes the scrolling but it looks a bit stretched, if that is okay with you: http://output.jsbin.com/waliqa

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. It's okay with me, not okay with my friend. That's why I asked here, because I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Okay, if my answer helped out please up-vote it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this ?

```
body {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/a/r9JRp");
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}
```

Comment: Or it's me, but it doesn't work? Nothing happens whatsoever.

Comment: Is that possible? Because I work with different div's in Wordpress.

Answer (score 1):

try this 
set background-size to cover

```
.home-3 {
    background-image: url("https://imgur.com/a/r9JRp");
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I did, yeah. Then it gets really stretched.